# Elements are not being inserted in different positions in the queue and value is not showing correctly

Tags: c, queue

Here is my `en_queue` function for insertion of new elements in different conditions.

```
void en_queue(int *queue,int max,int front,int rear)
{
    int ch1;
    printf("\n Enter element to add->");
    scanf("%d",&ch1);
    if(front==0 && rear==(max-1))
    {
        printf("\n Caution!! Queue Overflow!!");
    }
    else if(rear==(max-1) && front>0)
    {
        rear=0;
        queue[rear]=ch1;
        printf("\n %d added to the queue where front fo the queue has room but rear does not" ,ch1);
    }
    else if(front==-1 && rear==-1)
    {
        front=rear=0;
        queue[rear]=ch1;
        printf("\n %d added to the queue where this is the first element to the queue" ,ch1);
    }
    else 
    {
        rear++;
        queue[rear]=ch1;
        printf("\n %d added to the queue where the element added in the rear" ,ch1);
    }
}
```

and here is my `show_queue` function.

```
void show_queue(int *newqueue,int front,int rear)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",newqueue[i]);
    }
}
```

By the print statements, I examine that always the elements are being inserted into the first position. So, my best guess is the `rear` and `front` elements are not getting updated successfully but I am unable to find why. Also, I should have seen the correctly inserted first value at least by the `show_queue` function; instead, I am seeing garbage values but the values are **constant** viz. **4235968** everytime.

**UPDATE-** Here is the main function as requested.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

void en_queue(int *,int, int, int);
void show_queue(int *,int,int);

int main()
{
    int queue[MAX],front=-1,rear=-1,ch;
    do{
        printf("\n <<Queue MENU>>");
        printf("\n 1. Add Element");
        printf("\n 2. Delete Element");
        printf("\n 3. Show Queue");
        printf("\n 4. Exit menu");
        printf("\n Enter your choice->");
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: en_queue(queue,MAX,front,rear);
                break;
            /*  
            case 2: del_queue(queue,MAX,front,rear);
                 break;
             */
            case 3: printf("\n The queue is->");
                show_queue(queue,front,rear);
                break;

            case 4:exit(0);

            default: printf("\n Invalid Choice!!!");
                return 0;
        }
    } while(ch!=4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are aware of that when you change `front` and `rear` variables inside the `en_queue` function, it only changes the local copies in that function, not the variables you pass when you call the function?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Aah! Silly mistake. My bad. I should have used `pointers`

Comment: Please take more care with formatting your questions in the future. Not only was the code very difficult to read, it was also difficult to edit due to all of the tab characters you copied in from your original source.

Comment: @ChrisHayes, Thanks for the edit. I surely will. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    else 
    {
        rear++;
        queue[rear]=ch1;
        printf("\n %d added to the queue where the element added in the rear" ,ch1);
    }
```

change rear++ to *rear++ . It should solve your problem.

EDIT:

I tried you modified code and the problem seems to be *rear++, change it to

```
    *rear++ to (*rear)++
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `front` and `rear` are **passed by value**, thus their changes are not maintained outside this function.

Basically what is happening is that your `front` and `rear` variables are **copies** of those that exist in the calling function, say `main`. Thus changes made to it here are not reflected in the calling function.

You will have this issue with `dequeue` as well.

You might want to do one of the below, in reverse order of recommendation

1. Make them globals. - Not recommended, bad style, bug prone, only allows 1 queue.
2. Make them pointers to variables from the parent function
3. OOP style, make the queue into a `struct` which contains the array, `max`, `front` and `rear`, and pass that as a pointer.

Comment: Well, the insertion is doing fine now. But problem still remains with the display. Only the last element is being show now.

Comment: @Mistu4u do you mean just the last element or all elements equal to the last element?

Comment: The last element is only shown. For instance, suppose, I inserted, 4,5,6; then only 6 is shown! 4,5 are not shown.

Comment: One more question, you said" make them global". What advantage will I get from it? I guess, it will not make me independent of using pointers! Or the value will change even if I don't use pointers?

Comment: @Mistu4u yes, making them global means they are accessible in all corners of your programs, you dont need to use pointers, you dont need to even pass them around. However this is widely considered bad style and bug prone, and also prevents you from having more than 1 queue

Comment: Okay,so what about the display problem that still persists?

Comment: @Mistu4u I cant say, perhaps you can try to print the values of `front` and `rear`. Btw, this display function might not work if you add `dequeue` operation, and try to use the buffer circularly.